# How do I define Play assets and APIs to be served from a different sub-directory in production?

Tags: java, apache, scala, .htaccess, playframework-2.0

I'm using the Play 2 Framework. All assets are rendered correctly locally (but not production) if I'm not using versioned assets.

I have a requirement that locally assets are served from `localhost:9000/assets/*` however when in production the assets are to be served from `www.domain.com/subfolder/assets/*`

I also need to ensure that APIs are served from `localhost:9000/api/*` and `www.domain.com/subfolder/api/*` in a similar fashion in production. This is because there is already an application running on www.domain.com and it's assets are written and served using a totally different technology (PHP as opposed to Java / Scala).

My routes in play defines:

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/v/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Assets are loaded in like so in a `header.scala.html` file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("template/css/bootstrap.css").absoluteURL()" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css").absoluteURL()" />
```

I'm loading js assets in a `footer.scala.html` file like so:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("template/js/jquery.min.js").absoluteURL()"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("template/js/bootstrap.min.js").absoluteURL()"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("template/angular/angular.js").absoluteURL()"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="@routes.Assets.versioned("template/angular/angular-animate.js").absoluteURL()"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="@routes.Assets.versioned("template/angular/angular-cookies.js").absoluteURL()"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="@routes.Assets.versioned("template/angular/angular-route.js").absoluteURL()"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="@routes.Assets.versioned("template/angular/angular-resource.js").absoluteURL()"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="@routes.Assets.versioned("template/angular/angular-sanitize.js").absoluteURL()"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/app.js").absoluteURL()"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/appController.js").absoluteURL()"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/moment.js").absoluteURL()">    </script>
```

My play app is served up using a reverse proxy configuration in Apache which correctly serves up from www.domain.com/subfolder

However, the api's and assets are still wanting to be loaded from `www.domain.com` and not `www.domain.com/subfolder`

How can I load in assets correctly so they load correctly for both development and production?

I've looked at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsOverview as I say the assets are loaded in production in the `/assets` folder and not `subfolder/assets`

Any help much appreciated!

**Update**

I've tried the following as suggested by Kim's answer:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /sportsbook http://127.0.0.1:9000 retry=0
ProxyPassReverse /sportsbook http://127.0.0.1:9000 retry=0

ProxyHTMLEnable Off
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://localhost:9000 /sportsbook
<Location /sportsbook/>
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9000/
    SetOutputFilter proxy-html
    ProxyHTMLURLMap /           /sportsbook/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap /sportsbook            /sportsbook
</Location>
```

This however breaks the main site now (with no css or js working). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out the issue above and apparently it's easier just to serve the assets locally from localhost:9000/subfolder.

So basically I just changed all the assets to point to that directory instead both locally and in production with a proxy redirect in apache for localhost:9000/subfolder to website.com/subfolder

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier and more flexible to rewrite your request in the reverse proxy rather than change the paths in your application. The [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html) show you how to do that using `mod_rewrite`. It could be as simple as

```
RewriteRule "^/subfolder/(.*)" "http://playapp.example.com/$1" [P]
```

Comment: Thanks Kim I was thinking that would be an alternative solution. It just looked from the Play docs it was possible. I'd prefer to handle it all in app so I can test it. However you are probably right. I'll give it a try

Comment: You could post your play solution in your own answer.

Comment: Kim, I tried code in my update above (in the original question). Any ideas?

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately although I couldn't for the life of me figure out why. Probably something wrong with the Apache configuration that I haven't spotted. My answer above worked for now.